# Como restar horas de dos columnas de un jtable con datos de mysql

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8.2

hola amigos espero me puedan ayudar!!
necesito restas las horas de dos columnas de un jtable y mostrar el resultado de la resta en otra columna del jtable el resultado lo quiero mostrar en formato de horas, los datos los traigo de la base de datos y son de tipo time, este es el codigo que estoy utilizando para restar:

```
    fechaInicio = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse((String) modelo.getValueAt(i, 5));
            Date fecFinal = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse((String) modelo.getValueAt(i, 7));
            long tiempoInicial = fechaInicio.getTime();
            long tiempoFinal = fecFinal.getTime();
            resta = tiempoFinal - tiempoInicial; 
            atrasose = resta/(1000* 60);           
            modelo.setValueAt( atrasose,i, 10);
```

Comment: ¿y cual es el problema?

Comment: no me muestra los resultado en formato de horas

Comment: puedes agregar un ejemplo de datos de cada columna y como seria el de la columna resultado?